# Шифрованное данных Spring JPA и Hibernate

Tags: jpa, spring, hibernate, криптография

В проекте на java который пишется с использованием Spring JPA и Hibernate есть необходимость шифровать данные некоторый полей базы данных. Порывшись в интернет я нашел проект http://www.jasypt.org в связи с чем вопрос: 
Имел ли кто опыт решения подобных задач? 
Какие есть подводные камни, на что стоит обратить внимание?
Что можете порекомендовать?

Answer (score 1):

1. Шифруемые поля надо делать `BLOB` или как минимум `TEXT` (тогда с предварительным кодированием на Hex, Base64 или UUE).
2. Ключевые поля не надо шифровать :)
3. Пишется Hibernate бин/классик в котором геттеры/сеттеры будут сами шифровать/дешифровать значения полей - тогда все будет прозрачно (здесь самое место для применения jasypt'а)
4. Отдельно надо озаботиться хранением хэшей паролей и солей к паролям (по идеалогическим соображениям их надо хранить отдельно - хэши от солей)

Answer (score 0):

Добавляем зависимость:

```
compile group: 'org.jasypt', name: 'jasypt', version: '1.9.2'
```

Описываем конфигурацию:

```
@Configuration
public class EncryptorConfiguration {
    @Value("${application.security.encryptorAlgorithm}")
    private String encryptorAlgorithm;
    @Value("${application.security.masterPassword}")
    private String masterPassword;

    @Bean
    public StandardPBEStringEncryptor stringEncryptor() {
        StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
        encryptor.setPassword(masterPassword);
        encryptor.setAlgorithm(encryptorAlgorithm);
        return encryptor;
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class SecurityServiceImpl implements SecurityService {
    @Autowired
    private PBEStringCleanablePasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor;

    @Override
    public String decryptPassword(String hash) {
        return passwordEncryptor.decrypt(hash);
    }

    @Override
    public String encryptPassword(String password) {
        return passwordEncryptor.encrypt(password);
    }
}
```